# How to get values in multiple textbox using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, sql, codeigniter

```
public function update_assetrep()
{

    $checkedRep=$_POST['checkedRep'];
    $data['astrep']=$this->asset_model->get_astrep($checkedRep);

    $data['rep_options']=array_column($this->data['rep_logo'],'f_name','id' );

    $this->load->view('asset/asset_rep',$data);
    //$this->load->view('script/assets_script');
}

  <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <?
                            foreach($astrep as $astrep_detail)
                            {?>
                                <input type="hidden" name="astid" id="astid" class="form-control" value="<?=$astrep_detail['id']?>" style="width:225px;border-radius: 3px;"/>
                            <? }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here i have a code to get values from table, but it is displaying in separate text box. I want all the text box values. but i am getting only last the input box values in controller. can any one please tell me. any help could be appreciated.

Comment: console.log $POST and see output

Comment: _Small Point_ But wht are you styling a HIDDEN field  :)

Comment: All of your input fields have the same Id and same name !.

Comment: how to update values for autoincrement id is in Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 13 ) form in codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to change your input from:

<input type="hidden" name="astid" id="astid" class="form-control" value="<?=$astrep_detail['id']?>" style="width:225px;border-radius: 3px;"/>

To

<input type="hidden" name="astid[]" class="form-control" value="<?=$astrep_detail['id']?>" style="width:225px;border-radius: 3px;"/>

and receive same in controller as:
if(isset($_POST['astid'])){
 foreach($_POST['astid'] as $key => $data)
 {
  print '<pre>';
 var_dump($data);
 }
}
```